# RestKit crash -- RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m line 873

Tags: ios, core-data, crash, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am getting a crash report from my app in production. The stack trace doesn't include any of my code, rather points to code in RestKit itself where it is crashing. The crash itself is hard to reproduce on my side, and seems like some user in production is hitting an edge case. Below is the stack trace:

```
Thread : Crashed: NSManagedObjectContext 0x1743ecd00
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x000000019361c0b4 objc_retain + 20
1  MyApp                 0x00000001001e64c4 __78-[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation obtainPermanentObjectIDsForInsertedObjects:]_block_invoke (RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m:873)
2  CoreData                       0x0000000181b7d218 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 200
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000193c55954 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000193c5f1e4 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 76
5  CoreData                       0x0000000181b7d0d8 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 244
6  MyApp                 0x00000001001e62d8 -[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation obtainPermanentObjectIDsForInsertedObjects:] (RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m:870)
7  MyApp                 0x00000001001e34e4 __79-[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation performMappingOnResponseWithCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke345 (RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m:643)
8  MyApp                 0x000000010021c31c -[RKResponseMapperOperation willFinish] (RKResponseMapperOperation.m:317)
9  MyApp                 0x000000010021c980 -[RKResponseMapperOperation main] (RKResponseMapperOperation.m:404)
10 Foundation                     0x0000000182c601cc -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 636
11 Foundation                     0x0000000182d21f28 __NSOQSchedule_f + 228
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000193c55954 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000193c600a4 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1448
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000193c58a5c _dispatch_queue_invoke + 132
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000193c62318 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 720
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000193c63c4c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000193e3522c _pthread_wqthread + 816
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000193e34ef0 start_wqthread + 4
```

The crash message itself is:

> Crashed: NSManagedObjectContext 0x17198900
>   EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x915da43f

Any hints/directions as to how I can go about debugging this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the exception message? And are you creating any managed object instances yourself?

Comment: @Wain Added the crash message to post. And yes I do create managed objects at some places, mostly using "Magical Record" categories, passing [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQeueueManagedObjectContext as the context.

Comment: Do you save to the persistent store after creating them?

Comment: Not sure then really, perm id issues are usually related to unsaved / cross thread issues.

Comment: I am getting the same error. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this, had setup the core data stack twice on accident, removing the second initialization fixed the issue.